# x-Scaling of node without caption

Tags: tikz-pgf

Im using xscale to reduce the width of a node. This not only scales the shape but also the text. How can I x-scale the shape without the text?

```
  \node[mynode] (foo) [right=of ocr,fit={(ocr) (omr)},xshift=3cm,xscale=0.5] {FOO};
```

Comment: It would be good if you could make this into a full compilable example (starting from `\documentclass`). That would make it easier for people to try out the code and come up with solutions. As it is, everyone would have to spend time figuring out what `[mynode]` could be, that the `positioning` library is needed, and that two other nodes `ocr` and `omr` need to exist in the document.

Comment: You could scale the text back :-) using `\scalebox{2}{FOO}`.

Comment: @Martin: Is there an `xscalebox`? If yes, I think that's a valid answer.

Comment: @Jake: It's `\scalebox{<h-scale>}[<v-scale>]{<text>}`, so you would need to use `\scalebox{2}[1]{FOO}`.

Comment: @Martin: That approach would have the advantage that the vertical placement of the text remains unchanged. The `label=center:<text>` approach places the text right in the center of the node, whereas the node text would usually start a bit higher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `label=center:<text>` option to place the node text, and leave the actual node text empty:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (ocr) at (0,0) {a};
\node [draw] (omr) at (2,1) {b};
\node[draw] (foo) [fit={(ocr) (omr)},xscale=0.5,yshift=2cm] {FOO};
\node[draw] (foo) [fit={(ocr) (omr)},xscale=0.5,label=center:FOO] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: xscale with unscaled text]

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for single-line text you could scale the text back using the `\scalebox{<h-scale>}[<v-scale>]{<text>}` macro of `graphics` (which TikZ loads anyway). For a `xscale=0.5` you use `\scalebox{2}[1]{..}` to scale to text by 2x in the X but keep it unscaled (1x) at the Y axis.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [draw] (ocr) at (0,0) {a};
\node [draw] (omr) at (2,1) {b};
\node[draw] (foo) [fit={(ocr) (omr)},xscale=0.5] {\scalebox{2}[1]{FOO}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]