How do I scale nodes in TikZ without scaling the text inside?
I want a node that is shaped like a hexagon, but slightly stretched on the x-axis. Currently, I achieve this, but it stretches the text inside as well. How do I do this without stretching the text?
Here's my code if it helps:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}

\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}[ellipsenode/.style={ellipse, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum width=20mm, minimum height=10mm}, 
rectnode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum width=16mm, minimum height=9mm}, 
diamondnode/.style={diamond, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=5mm}, doublediamondnode/.style={diamond, draw=black!60, very thick, double, minimum size=5mm}, doublerectnode/.style={rectangle, draw=black!60, very thick, double, minimum width=16mm, minimum height=9mm}, 
hexnode/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, draw=black!60, very thick, minimum size=20mm, shape border uses incircle,xscale=1.5}
]

\node[rectnode] (prof) {Professor};

\node[rectnode] (stud) [right = of prof] {Student};

\node[hexnode] (isa) [below = of prof] {is\_a};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{figure}
\end{document}


Welcome. // Please add the missing lines so your code will compile. This way it can't. Thank you

This post can help you https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22766/x-scaling-of-node-without-caption
